# How to setState in React only after multiple fetches inside a loop are resolved

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch, setstate

In a React application, I'm trying to setState in my App only after I get lots of AJAX fetches resolved to avoid multiple useless re-rendering.

I have something like this so far:

```
const URL = https://url/api/
const NUM_OF_ITEMS = 10;
let allData = [];

componentDidMount() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
    this.fetchData(`${URL}${i}/`)  //ex. https://url/api/1/, https://url/api/2/...
  }
}

const fetchData = URI => {
  fetch(URI)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    allData = [ ...allData, data];
  })
  .catch( error => this.setState({ error });
}
```

Now I wanted to have just one single setState after all fetches are all resolved, and then save it all into localStorage:

```
this.setState({ allData })
localStorage.setItem("allData", JSON.stringify(allData))
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
componentDidMount() {
  const requests = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
    requests.push(this.fetchData(`${URL}${i}/`));
  }
  Promise.all(requests).then((arrayWithData) => {
     // here you can use setState with all the stuff
  });
}

const fetchData = URI => {
  fetch(URI)
  .then(response => response.json())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I guess something isn't working... I've placed console.logs of "requests" before and after Promise.all and they all return "undefined" :/

Comment: You must return the promise inside the fetchData: ```fetchData = URI => { return ....```

Comment: If I make the fetch inside the push `requests.push(fetch(`${URL}${i}/`).then(res => res.json()));` it works fine, but if I try to do the fetches through a callback as in the example, it always returns "undefined". I wonder why this happen?!

Comment: The return!! Brilliant!! That's what I was missing!! Thanks a lot @moonwave99 and @ha-ja!!